# how to validate inputs in ajax form

Tags: ajax, forms, validation

I have this ajax form with name, email and message and I want to validate the inputs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $form = $('form');
   $form.submit(function(){
         $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
      $("#inlocuire").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).html("<img src='images/de_multumire.png'/>").fadeIn(2000);
        });

        var message = $('textarea[name=message]').val('');
        var name = $('input[name=name]').val('');
        var email = $('input[name=email]').val('');
      },'json');
      return false;
   });

});
```

I tried to introduce this function but it is not working:

```
$('#form_id').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: validate
    });

    function validate(formData, jqForm, options) {
        var name = $('input[name=name]').fieldValue();
        var email = $('input[name=email]').fieldValue();
        var message = $('textarea[name=message]').fieldValue();

        if (!name[0]) {
            alert('Please enter a value for name');
            return false;
        }
        if (!email[0]) {
            alert('Please enter a value for email');
            return false;
        }
        if (!message[0]) {
            alert('Please enter a value for message');
            return false;
        }

        else {
        // here to send the form
                      }
```

The form is working fine...

Comment: There is a reasonably good validation plugin for JQuery which may be worth making use of: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: thanks. I am implementing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those having the same problem as me: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation